# Google analytics to show actual pageviews and % CTR with events

Tags: google-analytics

I have events setup for a link in my footer which is there in all pages of my CMS website. This is working perfectly fine. I laso have a dashboard created for this as shown below

Page title | Total events | Unique events

Now I want to also include the actual pageviews for the page in the same dashboard . So the dashboard should now have table with columns as below

Page title | Total events | Unique events | actual pageviews | CTR %

I know this can be done separately by creating 2 different widgets in dashboard, but is there a way to combine these both. Any help would be great.